# Trying to send email using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the Microsoft Graph API to send an email using the following code.

```cs
public static async Task SendEmailWithMicrosoftGraph()
{
    // Set up the Microsoft Graph API endpoint and version
    string graphApiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";

    // Set up the client application ID and secret
    string clientId = "CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE";
    string clientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_GOES_HERE";
    string tenantId = "TENANT_ID_GOES_HERE";

    // Set up the user's email address and message content
    string userEmail = "MY_EMAIL_HERE";
    string messageSubject = "Test email";
    string messageBody = "This is a test email sent via Microsoft Graph";

    // Set up the authentication context and acquire a token
    var authBuilder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
        .WithAuthority($ "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

    var authResult = await authBuilder.AcquireTokenForClient(new []
        {
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        })
        .ExecuteAsync();

    // Set up the HTTP client and add the access token to the authorization header
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

    // Set up the email message
    var emailMessage = new
    {
        message = new
        {
            subject = messageSubject,
                body = new
                {
                    contentType = "Text",
                        content = messageBody
                },
                toRecipients = new []
                {
                    new
                    {
                        emailAddress = new
                        {
                            address = userEmail
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    };

    // Convert the email message to a JSON string and send the email via Microsoft Graph
    var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailMessage);
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($ "{graphApiEndpoint}/users/{userEmail}/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Email sent successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to send email. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

When execution finishes, response.StatusCode is "FORBIDDEN". I have no idea why. I created an app registration. I created a client secret in the app registration. I have configured the Application Permissions so that it has Mail.Send. As far as I know I have done everything I am supposed to do to get this to work. What am I missing?

Edit:

I tried changing the line

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{graphApiEndpoint}/users/{userEmail}/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

to

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{graphApiEndpoint}/me/sendMail", new StringContent(jsonMessage, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Now the error I am getting is "Bad Request". According to the docs, this is only supposed to happen if the request body includes malformed MIME content. But I am using application/json as my content type.

Comment: As a starting point i would check the access token in https://jwt.io/ and see what roles are being returned in the token. If you don't see the correct roles it maybe due to consent not being granted. One other thing to keep in mind is that email address and userPrincipalName can in some case differ, if that's the case you can't use the email address as an identifier in the users endpoint

Comment: I tried looking at the token in jwt.io, but no roles were listed. As far as I can tell, I have granted consent for Mail.Send and Mail.Send.Shared, although it says Admin Consent is not required. Finally, I tried using $"{graphApiEndpoint}/me/sendMail" to see if using my email address was the problem and that returned the result "Bad Request". I am already specifying that the content type is "application/json", so I don't know why this is.

Comment: It sounds to me that you have assigned Delegate permission in your App registration rather the Application permissions. eg Mail.Send.Shared is a Delegate permission , Mail.Send is both Application and Delegate permission but the Application permission does require that you grant admin consent eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLEz1.png

Comment: It's also possible you have the right permission scopes requested but haven't completed the Admin Consent process. All Application scopes require admin consent before they are granted.